# Round decimal points in excel

Tags: excel, function, decimal

Hey guys I have a situation where I need to format a column to display APR(%) values in a certain way. Basically the values should be formatted like below:

```
Raw input    Formatted value
=========    ===============
0            0
0.0          0
4.4566       4.5
5.00         5
6            6
6.4          6.4
```

I tried creating this formula below but for some reason it doesn't round the number to 2 decimal places.

`=INT(ROUND(A1,1)*100)/100`

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to handle this?

UPDATE: So I am applying the function to the same cell as the number is in. For instance the A1 cell contains 4.566 value and I applied the function to that same cell and this doesn't seem to be working for Excel. Any other ways to do this?

P.S: Im using the MS Excel for Mac

Comment: see if this article helps you: http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/conditionally-displaying-decimal-places-in-excel-part-1

Answer (score 1):

Two steps

1. Format the cells to Number with one decimal place

[image]

2. Conditionally format the cells to a Number Format of General if the value is an integer

[image]

**EDIT:** Since you cannot conditionally format the number format in Excel for MAC, there are several workarounds.

If you do not mind changing the actual value, add a column which you will use to display the result.  Format the Column as `"General"`, and use this formula (assuming your "real data" is in column A:

```
=IF(A1<>INT(A1),ROUND(A1,1),A1)
```

Other options that may work would include using an event-triggered macro (if that can be done in Excel for Mac); and possibly you can create the worksheet in Excel for Windows and the conditional format might be recognized in Excel for Mac, even if you can't create it there.

Comment: Great solution there Ron but Im on Excel for Mac and I can only do style formats with the conditional formatting apparently. Do you by chance know if there is a way around it? This is what I have: http://jmp.sh/xSRSC7Z

Comment: @user3312508 No experience with Excel for Mac.  In Excel for Windows, before `number format` was allowed under Conditional Formatting, I would use an event triggered VBA macro to do that sort of thing.  I understand, also, that if you can create the worksheet in Excel for Windows, that Excel for Mac will recognize it (but I have no way of testing that).  If you can use a VBA solution, let me know.

Comment: @user3312508  See my edit for a method of using a Helper Column

Comment: I don't have the luxury of using additional columns Ron but I will try this method on a Windows machine and see if I can get this going.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Round-a-number-to-the-decimal-places-I-want-49b936f9-6904-425d-aa98-02ffb7f9a17b),

> Suppose that cell A1 contains 823.7825.
>
> ...
>
> =ROUND(A1,2) ... equals 823.78

You should be able to therefore apply this to your entire column to get the precision that you are after.

Rather than using `=INT(<another_cell_value>*100)/100` to derive the format you want, simply specify a custom format with the following:

> #,###.##

This way, you only get the number of decimal places that you specified in the ROUND function.

Comment: Sorry there was an error on my OP and I corrected it now. The `ROUND(A1,1)` doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your problem. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks Mike. But when I do 0.0 it ends up with a `.` and also 5.0 ends up with `5.`

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the trailing period with `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"."," "))," ",".")`, though you _might_ need to put this into another column - does that work for you?

Comment: I can't put the formula on a different column Mike :/

Comment: Why not? If it's to keep formatting looking nice, you can put the 'intermediate calculations' on a different sheet, which will ensure that the sheet you want to display does not have any messy values.

Comment: We are using this spreadsheet for data entry and each of these data cells has to be setup so that the data being entered gets formatted properly. This same data is then entered to a plugin that creates specific posts on a website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133373/discussion-between-mike-roberts-and-user3312508).